# Problems calling my own methods in Rhino android

Tags: javascript, java, android, rhino

I have been scripting Minecraft PE with Rhino, I have been existing libraries from both Java and android and I thought to myself why not make my own classes and script those now I made a android class...

**Android class**

```
package com.latch.to.modpe;
public class MainActivity extends android.app.Activity 
{
    private android.widget.Toast t;
    public void printToast()
    {
        t = new android.widget.Toast(getApplicationContext());
        t.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello Minecraft from my java file", android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

**And my JS File**

```
var ctx = com.mojang.minecraftpe.MainActivity.currentMainActivity.get();
var myClassFromFile = com.latch.to.modpe
function newLevel()
{
    ctx.runOnUiThread(new java.lang.Runnable() {
        run: function()
        {
            try
            {
                myClassFromFile.printToast();
            }
            catch(error)
            {
                clientMessage(error);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But when I ran it it gave me the error

```
Cannot call property printToast in object [JavaPackage com.latch.to.modpe]. It is not a function it is an object.
```